# How do I get a child object to edit using the same form in Seam?

Tags: jsf, seam

I have a class, let's call it Task.  Task can have sub-tasks.  Sub-tasks can have sub-tasks, etc.
I have a Seam JSF page that very nicely allows you to edit all the fields of any given Task.  I also have a list of sub-tasks, and I want a user to be able to click on that subtask, and begin to edit it.  So here's how I have that I've implemented:

```
<rich:dataList id="subTaskList" var="curSubTask" value="#{task.subTasks}">  
    <s:link view="/party/edit.xhtml" propagation="nest">  
        <h:outputText value="#{curSubTask.title}"/>  
        <f:param name="taskId" value="#{curSubTask.id}"/>  
    </s:link>  
</rich:dataList>
```

When i click on the link, the and on the URL the taskId changes, I get a new conversation number, but there is no change in the data.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Can you show your page.xml and the rest of your page?

Comment: The rest of the page works.  It saves, cancels, goes back.  Adds other stuff etc.  There is no page.xml file.
Getting to this page via the parent also works. (URL: http://blah.com/party/edit.seam?taskId=1)  However, if the child id is 2: (URL: http://blah.com/party/edit.seam?taskId=2) does not work, if you click on the link.  If you go there directly it does work, after ending the conversation.  I've tried it with nest, and join with the same results.
It's something with conversations and going to the same page I believe, I just don't know what.

Comment: So how are you setting the value of taskId in your Bean? Are you using the RequestParameter annotation or retrieving it from the parameter map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I personally do is set the field in the context using f:setPropertyActionListener as follows

```
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{curSubTask}"
            target="#{selectedTask}" />
```

and then redirect to the page in pages.xml, the page simply uses selectedTask. I try to avoid using page params if possible.